# Angular2-csv How to add headers?

Tags: angular

I have installed Angular2-csv. And now it creates csv file, but what i want is to add my headers, i dont want that Angular2-csv added automatically. Any suggestion how can i do that and is that possible?

This is my method now:

```
exportExcel(data) {
        let options = {
            fieldSeparator: ',',
            quoteStrings: '"',
            decimalseparator: '.',
            showLabels: true,
            showTitle: false
        };
        new Angular2Csv(data, 'Detaljni izvještaj', options);

    }
```

Comment: You should put your headers in the `data[0]` position of your data array

Comment: im getting data from api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone wants to add customized column names to the header. Just create an array with column names:

const head = ['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email']

new Angular2Csv(array, 'mycsv', {headers: (head)});

I hope this will help those who want to use customized names in the header.

Answer (score 5):

```
new Angular2Csv(data, 'Detaljni izvještaj', { headers: Object.keys(data[0]) });
```

Find the details in the link https://github.com/javiertelioz/angular2-csv/issues/27

Answer (score 2):

If your have more options than just 'headers' you can write:

```
 const options = {
      fieldSeparator: ';',
      quoteStrings: '"',
      decimalseparator: ',',
      showLabels: true,
      showTitle: false,
      useBom: true,
      headers: ['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email']
    };

const file = new Angular2Csv(jsonData, filename, options);
```